# Wrong GCC 9 (and higher) optimization of memcmp with -fno-inline

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

There is a small `func` function which compares a memory block against a static const zeroed array. Here is a primitive example to illustrate the problem:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

#define MAX_BYTES (256)

inline int my_memcmp(const void * mem1, const void * mem2, const size_t size)
{
    const auto *first  = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(mem1);
    const auto *second = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(mem2);
    if (size < 8)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (*first != *second) return (*first > *second) ? 1 : -1;
            ++first; ++second;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return std::memcmp(mem1, mem2, size);
}

bool func(const uint8_t* in, size_t size)
{
  size_t remain = size;
  static const uint8_t zero_arr[MAX_BYTES] = { 0 };

  while (remain >= MAX_BYTES)
  {
    if (my_memcmp(in, zero_arr, MAX_BYTES) != 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    remain -= MAX_BYTES;
    in += MAX_BYTES;
  }

  return true;
}
```

- Compiler: gcc 9.1 and higher
- Compiler flags: `-fno-inline -O3`
- Godbolt disassemble link: https://godbolt.org/z/P8vKGq
- Godbolt program execution link: https://godbolt.org/z/qr8f16

In case I use `-fno-inline` compiler flags, the compiler tries to optimize the code above and generates only 2 lines of code for `my_memcmp` function, however it seems like it always returns 0:

```
my_memcmp(void const*, void const*, unsigned long) [clone .constprop.0]:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

The problem cannot be reproduced until I add `-fno-inline` (I met the problem when I compiled  the code for coverage testing, so I needed to add no-inline to make a report more clear.) Also I've found that gcc 8 doesn't have such problem. Is there a reasonable explanation or is it just a bug in both GCC 9 and 10?

Comment: My educated guess is that since the compiler can know that `my_memcmp` can only be used inside the module it can safely assume that the only call is the one in `func` and optimize `my_memcpy` based on this context.

Comment: @Johan: Yes, I think you're right.  Disabling inlining doesn't disable interprocedural optimization, such as constant propagation in this case.  If you call `my_memcmp` from somewhere else with different arguments, the compiler will generate a separate version of the function for that case, as [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xbWra4).  So I think it's not a bug at all, but rather clever (and correct) optimization.

Comment: The compiler can tell that the array is zeroed, so it can assume that your `memcmp` will return 0. To 'fix' this you could try randomizing the array values.

Comment: There is something fishy after all. For the given value of `MAX_BYTES`, the `my_memcmp` should fall back to `std::memcmp` and given that we can not know anything about the `in` parameter to `func` it is not enough to only look at the first character.

Comment: @Johan The point is 'func' function works incorrectly with the 'optimization', because returns 0 instead of doing a comparison. That is why I'm asking the question.  Please see https://godbolt.org/z/qr8f16 and find that the results for GCC 9 and 8 are different.

Comment: @NateEldredge Please see my comment above.

Comment: Yes, I see now.  It helps to have the actual test case.  I guess one note is that because of interprocedural optimization, we can't really look at the code for `my_memcmp` alone; we have to take `func` and `my_memcmp` together and figure out what is wrong between the two of them.

Comment: @NateEldredge ...or we have to see what was changed between GCC 8 and 9?

Comment: It looks like it's still reproducible if you remove everything from `my_memcmp` except for the `return std::memcmp(...);`.  Also, it looks like gcc trunk works correctly, so if it's a bug it may already be fixed.  `-fno-builtin` also makes it go away, suggesting that it is a problem with the way `std::memcmp` is optimized as a builtin.

Comment: I noticed your code on Compiler Explorer has `MAX_BYTES` defined to 256, unlike the question, which defines to 9. Please **never** do that, your CE link should match the code in your question. Mismatches cause problems for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is GCC bug 95189, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95189

Basically, GCC can emit specialized code for memcmp if one of the buffers has known contents, but this specialization doesn't work correctly if it encounters a zero byte (because it's special for other functions such as strcmp).

It appears already fixed on GCC main development branch (trunk), but the fix was not backported to 9.x and 10.x release branches yet.

This minimal repro in C is miscompiled at -O2, a similar example is mentioned in the comments of the bug:

```
int f(const char *p)
{
    return __builtin_memcmp(p, "\0\0\0", 4);
}
```